# In Java, I want to convert a short[] to a double[]

Tags: java, double, short

I am using a `short[]` array:

```
short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
```

I have a method that takes as a parameter type `double[]`, so I cannot pass it as-is.  I need to make it into a `double[]`.  The best thing that I've done is to make a new object and loop through and convert, like this:

```
double[] transformed = new double[bufferSize];

for (int j=0;j<bufferSize;j++) {
    transformed[j] = (double)buffer[j];
}
```

I have not yet even tested the above approach, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: For something this simple, I wouldn't even waste time looking for an alternative.

Comment: I which java would give uns some operator like short[] arr=new short[blub]; int[] otherArr=new int[blub]; otherArr[]=(int)arr; or something. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's as good as it gets, though you can just use `buffer.length` instead of `buffersize`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Laurence is correct and should be accepted, but it's worth noting that there is more than one way to copy an array in Java.  See [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=3) article for an explanation of each method.

- use the various copyOf and copyOfRange methods of the Arrays class
- use System.arraycopy - useful when copying parts of an array
- call its clone method, and do a cast - the simplest style, but only a shallow clone is performed
- use a for loop - more than one line, and needs a loop index

Comment: those details are not relevant here.  The OP does not need a regular array copy.

Comment: I just thought it would be useful supplementary data - thats why I said Laurence's answer should be accepted.