# short to double value

Tags: java, double, type-conversion, unsigned, short

I'm having problems converting `short` value to `double` in Java. I have real numbers represented as 16 bit unsigned value (`short` in java). When I read them, I want to convert them to `double`, but after doing `(double) value`, I'm getting a wrong result, for instance in one case by using `System.out.println(value)` I get `0.0`, but result should be `0.00034`.

```
 double[][] dataD = null;
 short[][] dataS = null;
 try {
    fits = new Fits(path); // here im readinf fits file
    switch(bitpix) { // bitpix contains information about size of data
       case 16: dataS = ((short[][]) fits.getHDU(0).getKernel()); break;
       ...
    }
 } catch (FitsException e) {}
 catch (IOException e) {}
 for( int i = 0; i < dataS.length;  i++ )
    for( int j = 0 ; j <dataS[0].length ; j++ )  {
       switch(bitpix) {
          case 16: dataD[i][j] = 0.0; 
             if( dataS[i][j] < 0 ) dataD[i][j] = dataS[i][j] + 32768;
             else dataD[i][j] = dataS[i][j] ;   
          break;
       }
```

Comment: Show us your wrong result. All `short`s are exactly representable as `double`s.

Comment: How did you represent 0.00034 in a short?

Comment: The question has been asked before:

 [Look here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424881/in-java-i-want-to-convert-a-short-to-a-double

Comment: Im reading FITS file, it contains some data represented as array of unsigned values. In this case it is 16bit value ( short in java ) but in real it is double value. I want to convert it to double. Im using matlab to read this file and it shows 0.000034 but i was not able to do the same in my program

Comment: An unsigned 16-bit value is _always_, without exception, an integer.  0.000034 is not.

Comment: @viktor.radovic, show us the java code. Include short and double variables' declaration and initialization, calls to System.out, expected and actual result.

Comment: could have problem in reading. reading 0.000034 from file as a short would be problem. look at your format syntax

Comment: maybe 0.000034 is far greater than the max. value of a short in terms of bitwise representation. do you know which(HO dword or LO dword) part is used for the part after the dot? or none?

Comment: unfortunately, i don`t know, i could not find that anywhere

Comment: Where exactly do you expect to see 0.000034?

Comment: 0.000034 is approx 1/29412. There is no simple way to get this number from a short.

Comment: I'm wondering what is the return type of `fits.getHDU(0).getKernel()`

Comment: it returns row data from fits file, just bits. In this FITS library it returns Object[][] witch has to be converted to proper type - in this case it is short[][]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are dividing your short numbers before converting them to `double`. don't do

```
short s = 123;
double d = (double) (s / 100);
```

instead do

```
short s = 123;
double d = (double) (s / 100.0);
```

to avoid integer devision.

Comment: i think he tried : short var=0.00034; double var2=(double)var;

Comment: there's no need to cast int/short/double to double.

Comment: `short` is no floating point data type. So there is no `0.1` only full numbers.

Comment: First i have to convert form unsigned to signed by using value & 0xFFF after that im just casting to double

Comment: @viktor.radovic do you mean `& 0xFFFF`? A short is a whole number and will still be a whole number when you cast to a double.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
Short sObj = new Short("10");
double d = sObj.doubleValue();
```

This should be ok.

Comment: This is quite a roundabout way of saying `(double)shortVar`.